# How to preserve the Firefox "Allow Windows single sign-on for Microsoft, work, and school accounts" with Python Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

Is it possible to make sure that `Allow Windows sigle sign-on for Microsoft, work, and school accounts` is checked when using the browser driver for Firefox in Selenium?

Everytime I re-run Selenium I end up with it unchecked.

[image: Mozilla Firefox settings, Logins and Passwords Allow Windows single sign-on for Microsoft work, and school accounts checked]

Comment: Are you running it with a Firefox profile?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan I guess not...should I?

Comment: It basically allows you to run it with some settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
opts = FirefoxOptions()
...
prof = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
prof.set_preference('network.http.windows-sso.enabled', True)
...
executable_path = ...
service = FirefoxService(executable_path=executable_path, firefox_profile=prof)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=opts)
```

Comment: Another way is to run the driver: driver.get('about:config') and set network.http.windows-sso.enabled automatically or manually.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, this is the second possible method that I used:

```
preference = 'network.http.windows-sso.enabled'
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
 
try:
   driver.get('about:config')
   locator = By.ID, 'warningButton'
   btn = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator)) 
   btn.click()
except Exception as e:
   raise Exception(f'Failed to launch the browser process!\n{e}')

try:
   locator = By.ID, 'about-config-search'
   input_search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator))     
   input_search.clear()
   input_search.send_keys(preference)
   locator = By.XPATH, '//table[@id="prefs"]/tr/th'
   key = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator)).get_attribute('innerText')
   val = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="prefs"]/tr/td').get_attribute('innerText')
   if key==preference and val=='false':
      locator = By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[class="button-toggle semi-transparent"]'
      btn = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator)) 
      btn.click()
   else:
      raise Exception('Something is wrong')
except Exception as e:
   raise Exception(f'Failed to launch the browser process!\n{e}')
 
driver.get(...)        #office365 website
```

Good luck!